# Image onload is not getting called

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I am trying to read an Image from external URL as Data URL.
Here is my code

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
img = new Image();

img.onload = function(){
    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.width = img.width;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    console.log(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"));
    canvas = null;
};
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
img.src = "http://pierre.chachatelier.fr/programmation/images/mozodojo-original-image.jpg";
```

Here onload of Image is not getting called. 
But when I Remove `img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';` onload is getting called and browser throws error `SecurityError: The operation is insecure.`
This error is from Mozilla.
Chrome giving error -

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

Can't test on IE as on a Linux machine

I can't find what else is wrong with the code.

Comment: You can read the image on server side by downloading it and returning from your own domain, which makes the request secure.

Comment: Does the security error appear on every browser ? I remember google-chrome make sometimes more security block than others.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Can't do that as Images will be served from a different server.
@Aracthor Chrome giving error `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.`

Comment: If the image host is under your control, you can configure the headers to allow your domain to access it or even to allow annon requests.

Comment: on moz documentation there's an example on storing an image from a foreign origin, [check it out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image#Example.3A_Storing_an_image_from_a_foreign_origin)

Comment: @maioman that is not client side only, you can see that it tells how to configure cors headers on server side too.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I am not sure if I will be able to configure that on Hosting server. Now everyone is out of office so can't confirm now.

Comment: You could try a proxy like http://www.whateverorigin.org or http://anyorigin.com or roll your own

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown yes, like you say,  that should be the procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code. Now I am sending the bytes from server instead of Image url using code :

```
URL u = new URL(url);
InputStream is = u.openStream();
byte[] = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only apply `canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg")` to a file that exists in your project. According to my idea, you can use remote image from other website to convert it to `base64` image. One solution is, to **save** the image from the website you want to get it, then apply `canvas.toDataURL()` to that saved image.